# Want to change default java version to 1.8.xx

Tags: java, jdk, openjdk, oracle

I downloaded Oracle JDK-8 using 
`sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer` and set this version to default using `sudo update-alternatives --config java`
but when I run `java -version`
I get

```
java version "10.0.1" 2018-04-17
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.3 (build 10.0.1+10)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.3 (build 10.0.1+10, mixed mode)
```

Comment: yet /usr/lib/jvm contains the folder of java-8-oracle and version shows up to be 10.0.1

Answer (score 7):

Have you tried using `update-java-alternatives` instead
of `update-alternatives`?

Show the list of available alternatives:

```
sudo update-java-alternatives -l
```

Select one of them:

```
sudo update-java-alternatives -s java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64
```

Comment: $sudo update-java-alternatives -l
[sudo] password for harry: 
java-8-oracle                  1081       /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle

**************************************************************************

$ java -version
java version "10.0.1" 2018-04-17
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.3 (build 10.0.1+10)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.3 (build 10.0.1+10, mixed mode)

Comment: I don't know how I have java 10.0.1 installed on my system

Comment: have you  run $sudo update-java-alternatives -s java-8-oracle

Comment: @HaripalBaluja: Could you please [edit] your post when you want to add information? Especially file or program output [listings](/editing-help#code) (with the help of the `{}` button in the editor toolbar) will be much more readable there; alternatively you can use a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) for longer listings and include the link of your pastie in your question. Overall it’s best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons. Thanks.

Comment: how to install a new java version? I only have version 11 installed